# created date for sharepoint list item is not coming correct when I fetch it through rest

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have one list in sharepoint where user created one item on 25/11/2019,9:57PM but when today I tried to fetch data through REST get method it shows 26/11/2019,3:27AM.
When I look item in sharepoint list it shows correct date but when I try to fetch using REST it changes.
I want same date as in back end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint store datatime as UTC time so you need to convert to local datatime.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function test() {
            var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
            var web = context.get_web();
            var regionalSettings = web.get_regionalSettings();
            var localDueDate = regionalSettings.get_timeZone().utcToLocalTime('2019-02-26T17:15:00Z');
            context.executeQueryAsync(
                Function.createDelegate(this, function () {
                    console.log(localDueDate.m_value);
                }),
                Function.createDelegate(this, function (sender, args) {
                    alert('Query failed. Error: ' + args.get_message());
                })
            );
        }
    </script>
    <input id="Button1" type="button" onclick="test()" value="button" />
```